# How to get banner name

Tags: magento-1.9, promotional-banner

I've been trying to get the banner name in the code below without success.

```
    <?php $bannersContent =  $this->getBannersContent() ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ($bannersContent as $bannerId => $content): ?>
        <li name="banner-<?php echo $bannerId; ?>" onclick="dataLayer.push({
   'event':'promotionClick',
   'ecommerce': {
     'promoClick': {
       'promotions': [

    {
        'id': '<?php echo $bannerId; ?>',
        'name': '<?php/*  echo $bannerId->getData('name'); */ ?>',
        'creative': '',
        'position': '',

    },


]
    }
  }
});"><?php echo $content?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

Any ideas about how to do this?

Comment: Which banner are you talking about ?

Comment: Enterprise banner

Answer (score 0):

You can see all attributes or information of banner by printing that variable.

First you see what values are comes in `$banner` variable.

```
<?php foreach ($bannersContent as $banner): ?>
     <?php echo "<pre>"; 
      print_r($banner); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In above code you can see all information about banner so you can easily find the name of banner.

Comment: The variable $banner just returns the actual banner. Looks like I could get it from the banner id some way?